# openstack nova-compute get AccessRefused error

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

Installing `openstack` **ocata**. 
When i install and configure the compute node i need to restart the `nova-compute` service, but this gives me the error below. 
When i do the `Hypervisor list` in controller node i do not get any output.

```
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/_drivers/amqpdriver.py", line 402, in _send
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova     msg.update({'_reply_q': self._get_reply_q()})
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/_drivers/amqpdriver.py", line 383, in _get_reply_q
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova     conn = self._get_connection(rpc_common.PURPOSE_LISTEN)
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/_drivers/amqpdriver.py", line 374, in _get_connection
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova     purpose=purpose)
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/_drivers/common.py", line 402, in __init__
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova     self.connection = connection_pool.create(purpose)
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/_drivers/pool.py", line 144, in create
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova     return self.connection_cls(self.conf, self.url, purpose)
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/_drivers/impl_rabbit.py", line 611, in __init__
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova     self.ensure_connection()
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/_drivers/impl_rabbit.py", line 710, in ensure_connection
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova     self.ensure(method=lambda: self.connection.connection)
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/_drivers/impl_rabbit.py", line 817, in ensure
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova     ret, channel = autoretry_method()
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 436, in _ensured
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova     return fun(*args, **kwargs)
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 507, in __call__
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova     self.revive(create_channel())
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 242, in channel
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova     chan = self.transport.create_channel(self.connection)
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 741, in connection
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova     self._connection = self._establish_connection()
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 696, in _establish_connection
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova     conn = self.transport.establish_connection()
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/transport/pyamqp.py", line 116, in establish_connection
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova     conn = self.Connection(**opts)
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 180, in __init__
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova     (10, 30),  # tune
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/abstract_channel.py", line 67, in wait
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova     self.channel_id, allowed_methods, timeout)
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 274, in _wait_method
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova     wait()
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/abstract_channel.py", line 69, in wait
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova     return self.dispatch_method(method_sig, args, content)
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/abstract_channel.py", line 87, in dispatch_method
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova     return amqp_method(self, args)
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 530, in _close
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova     (class_id, method_id), ConnectionError)<br>
2017-09-02 23:11:52.030 8491 ERROR nova AccessRefused: (0, 0): (403) ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism AMQPLAIN.
                                        For details see the broker logfile.
```

What can be the solution to this? Thanks in advance

Comment: how did you endup solving this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neha,
1. Check rabbitmq-server service is active and running
2. Ensure the rabbitmq-server credentials provided are correct in nova config file

Comment: Even i have correct username/password on rabbitMQ but still showing same error